# Determine number of blocks in a cache

Tags: cpu-cache

The question is: We need to design a cache with cache size of 128K bytes, block (line) size of 8 words, and word size of 4 bytes. Consider a computer with 64-bit physical address. The cache is addressed by physical address

I need clarification on this: if we have 128k bytes and each block equals 32 bytes (8*4), do we have: 1.($128$ x $2^{10}$)/$32$ or 2. $128k/32$. The problem is that the first gives 4096 blocks and the second gives 4000 blocks. Which is the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

The common usage is for KB, MB, GB, TB, and so on to denote powers of 2 rather than powers of 10. There are ways to denote powers of 10, but they are infrequently used. See for example the Wikipedia page on [kibibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte).